# is there a way to increase the wait time for $this->open()

Tags: selenium, phpunit

In one test i am writing, there is a page which takes a while to load when you go to it and i get exceptions after the timeout of 40000s (my default)

when i use `$this->waitForPageToLoad()` i always pass in how long i am expected to wait that way if someone has their wait time set to say 20000s i'm not being called up when they run my test and it keeps failing

i want to do the same for `$this->open()` but it even having `$this->waitForPageToLoad("100000")` i still get the exception

so i'm wondering, is there away to incrase the wait time for `$this->open()` like with `$this->waitForPageToLoad()`

NOTE: i use `$this->open()` as a shortcut otherwise i'll be navigating a crap ton of pages and the purpose of the test is to check this one page, not the way leading to it (since that is done is a different Test Class)

Answer (score 1):

`$this->setTimeout(50000)`
You can configure time insert of `50000` what ever you like

Answer (score 0):

to set up selenium wait time for element use this:
$this->timeouts()->implicitWait(5000);